# Find an analytic function that maps the plane with the slit $[-1,1]$ onto the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Find an analytic function that maps the plane with the slit $[-1,1]$ onto the upper half plane

Normaly I can find the function from $3$ points easily, but this problem doesn't give me any point. So I know that $z$ is in the plane that delete the line segment on the real aaxis from $-1$ to $1$ and I know that the image is only cover the upper half plane, so I guess $f(z)$ must have $z^2$ in it? or the whole expression is square?

However, these infor is not enough for me to get the 3 points, I wonder if anyone would please give me a hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A useful conformal map to know is
$$
w = \frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)
\tag{*}$$
It maps the inside of the unit circle onto the Riemann sphere except the interval $[-1,1]$; and also maps the outside of the unit circle to the same thing.

Here is a picture from the web:
[image: conformal]
$z=\xi+i\eta = \rho e^{i\theta}$ is on the right, $w = u+iv$ is on the left.  The outsde of the disk on the right maps to the outside of the slit on the left.  Circles of constant $\rho$ on the right map to ellipses (with foci $1,-1$) on the left.  Radial lines with constant $\theta$ on the right map to hyperbolas (with foci $1,-1$) on the left.

Of course the inside (or outside) of the unit clrcle is easily mapped to the upper half-plane by a linear fractional transformation.

So, use the inverse of the map (*) to map the plane without the slit onto the exterior of the disk, then a linear fractional transformation to map the exterior of the disk onto the upper half plane.

Comment: what if you have a negative $z$, say $z=-2-i$ the $w= \frac{-6-2i}{5}$, the image of this point is on the lower half plane, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still can't see it, I checked around and know this is a Joukowski map, I also find the inverse $z=2w \pm \sqrt{4w^-1}$, nad tried to let $w=u+iv$ but it still doesn't go anywhere, can you explain a little bit more please.

Comment: from your picture, the slit $[-1,1]$ is on the $w$-plane, but I think in my question, the slit is on $z$-plane, right?

Comment: So that is why you need to use the inverse of the map (*).

Comment: I'm sorry, just want to make sure that I understand this correctly, by saying "Of course the inside (or outside) of the unit clrcle is easily mapped to the upper half-plane by a linear fractional transformation." you mean take $w^2$?

Comment: No, $w^2$ does not do this.  Find a *linear fractional transformation* to do it.  It will map the circle onto the real line.

Comment: GEdgar, in my notes I have that the map $(*)$ maps the outside of the unit circle into the upper half plane (which is open so the real axis is not included). You say that one needs to take the inverse of (*) but that's not where the transformation should start, it should start with $\mathbb C-[1,1]$, no?

Answer (score 1):

The 360 degree angle at $1$ has to be reduced to $180$, so put in a $\sqrt{x-1}$.
The other key point, at $-1$, has to be moved to $\infty$, so put in a $1/(x+1)$.
Going in a full circle around the slit must turn into an ordinary loop in the upper half plane.  So $\sqrt{(x-1)/(x+1)}$ does not change sign.
Lastly, the boundary is the imaginary axis, so multiply by $i$.
$i\sqrt{(x-1)/(x+1)}$

Comment: can you explain it a little bit further please? For example , why $-1$ is move to $\infty$, so $f(-1) = \infty$?

Comment: The double line from $-1$ to $1$ has to become the whole real line.  So at one point it becomes infinite.  Also, I have to deal with the $360^{\circ}$ at $-1$, so it is convenient to deal with both as I did.  It is tricky to make, for example, $0$ in the upper half plane of the slit go to infinity without making $0$ in the lower half-plane of the slit go to infinity.

Comment: Why your answer does not match with the answer of the book: $w=\sqrt{\frac{z+1}{1-z}}$?

Comment: The reciprocal of the upper half plane is the lower half plane

Comment: what ? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Bring the $i$ inside the square-root and it becomes -1.  Now my answer and the book answer are reciprocal.  If the book answer gives the upper half-plane, the reciprocal of all those points is the lower half-plane.  So my answer gives the lower half-plane.  But every number has two square-roots; the other square-roots  give the upper half-plane.